# How to select/count disabled/enabled elements in Playwright?

Tags: javascript, playwright

I want to check how many (if it's like in config) I have disabled elements.

In Cypress it'd be like that:

```
cy.visit('https://example.cypress.io/commands/actions');

const disabledElementsLength = 0;
const enabledElementsLength = 9;

cy.get('button').not(':disabled').should((elem) => {
  expect(elem).to.have.length(enabledElementsLength);
});

cy.get(`button`).filter(':disabled').should((elems) => {
  expect(elems).to.have.length(disabledElementsLength);
});
```

but I can't make it work for myself in Playwright

I have page with

```
import { selectors, expect, request } from '@playwright/test';

export class MyPage {
   readonly element: Locator;
   constructor(public readonly page: Page) {
      selectors.setTestIdAttribute('data-test-id');
      this.element = this.page.locator(`[data-test-id^="specific-element"]`);
   }
}
```

I thought of just filter over... but seems like it doesn't have method filter available to this array of elements

```
async selectDisabledElements() {
    return this.element.evaluate((elements) =>
      elements.filter((button: any) => element.disabled),
    );
  }
```

Comment: "but I can make it work for myself in Playwright" -- do you mean "can't"? Please share your Playwright attempt(s) as a [mcve].

Comment: I gave Cypress attempt, if it'd work for me in PW I'd not ask here. I tried few ideas, what I wrote now in edit is the closest idea I got.

Comment: I'm not asking for the functioning Playwright code. I'm asking for the non-functioning Playwright code. We can't help with code we can't see! Also include an example site you're automating, so it's clear what the goal is. Thanks. Now that I can see your code, I can make a suggestion. Did you try `evaluateAll` instead of `evaluate` so that `elements` is an array? That said, I don't think it'll work anyway, since you can't return DOM nodes from `evaluate` callbacks. Try running the [filter Node-side](https://playwright.dev/docs/locators#filtering-locators) instead of browser-side.

Comment: I think `[data-test-id^="specific-element"][disabled]` will work as well.

Comment: ok thanks, that last idea can work for me, thanks

Comment: If you have an answer, please post it as a [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) rather than an [edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/262807/6243352). Thanks. I've [rolled back](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/289345/6243352) the current answer.

Comment: From testing viewpoint, it's a very weak check to just count total no. of enabled/ disabled elements .

Comment: I would rather have individual strong checks on the control along with other properties like text/label/value.

Comment: yes, I understand that, and I totally agree that counter isn't "best idea" - it's more of sanity check for debugging for me - from testing standpoint e2e tests shouldn't check any texts, but flows, it's why you need lower layers of tests for those specific checks if proper texts are shown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try using `:disabled` directly on your CSS selectors, and using `:not` to invert the condition:

```js
import {expect, test} from "@playwright/test"; // ^1.38.0

const html = `<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<body>
<button disabled>A</button>
<button>B</button>
<button disabled>C</button>
<button disabled>D</button>
<button>E</button>
</body>
</html>`;

test.beforeEach(({page}) => page.setContent(html));

test("3 disabled buttons", async ({page}) => {
  await expect(page.locator("button:disabled")).toHaveCount(3);
});

test("2 enabled buttons", async ({page}) => {
  await expect(page.locator("button:not(:disabled)")).toHaveCount(2);
});
```

With test ids, you can either use `[data-test-id="foo"]` in the above code, or `getByTestId` as in the following example:

```js
import {expect, selectors, test} from "@playwright/test";

const html = `<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<body>
<button data-test-id="foo" disabled>A</button>
<button data-test-id="foo">B</button>
<button data-test-id="foo" disabled>C</button>
<button data-test-id="foo" disabled>D</button>
<button data-test-id="foo">E</button>
</body>
</html>`;

test.beforeEach(({page}) => {
  selectors.setTestIdAttribute("data-test-id");
  return page.setContent(html);
});

test("3 disabled buttons", async ({page}) => {
  const loc = page
    .getByTestId("foo")
    .locator(":scope:disabled");
  await expect(loc).toHaveText(["A", "C", "D"]);
});

test("2 enabled buttons", async ({page}) => {
  const loc = page
    .getByTestId("foo")
    .locator(":scope:not(:disabled)");
  await expect(loc).toHaveText(["B", "E"]);
});
```

Comment: I made it even without filter, just chained `locator` after `getByTestId`, and it went through